# The equivalent of "tempered distributions" for the Mellin transform?

Tags: distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis, mellin-transform

The Fourier transform is defined for tempered distributions. For these distributions, the test functions are those functions decreasing more quickly at $\pm \infty$ than $|x|^{-n}$ for all n.

In contrast, the Mellin transform is defined for functions $(0,\infty) \to \Bbb R$. So what are the corresponding "tempered distributions" here? Is the idea that the functions are decreasing faster than $|\log x|^{-n}$ for all n? Or is there something more subtle to it?

Also, does this space of test functions (and its continuous dual space of distributions) have a name?

Comment: Just a remark about your definition of the space of test functions for tempered distributions: the test functions and *all their derivatives* have to decrease at infinity faster than any polynomial. Otherwise you will have some troubles with derivatives of tempered distributions (they would be not necessarily tempered).

Comment: The terms "test functions" (the space $D$) and "distributions" (the space $D'$) are already a good name=) You also have "Schwartz functions" $S$ and "tempered distributions" $S'$. However, I have never seen any widely accepted name or notation for the functions with "decreasing faster than $|\ln x|^{-n}$" behaviour.